# Data tranformation in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have below data stored in variable "json_ls"

print(json_ls)

```
[{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517a5'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517a6'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517a7'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517a9'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517aa'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517ab'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517ac'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517ad'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517ae'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517af'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517b0'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517b1'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b2'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b3'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b4'}]
```

I need to convert the above data and get the result as shown below. I want to group the data for each batch and keep all respective recipient_id, status within array.

```
[
{'batch_number': '1001a', 
'recipients': 
[{'recipient_id': '5517a5', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517aa', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517ab', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517b2', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517b3', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517b4', 'status': 'Take'}]}, 

{'batch_number': '1001b', 
'recipients': 
[{'recipient_id': '5517a6', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517ac', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517ad', 'status': 'Take'}]}, 

{'batch_number': '1001c', 
'recipients': 
[{'recipient_id': '5517a7', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517ae', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517af', 'status': 'Take'}]}, 

{'batch_number': '1001d', 
'recipients': 
[{'recipient_id': '5517a9', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517b0', 'status': 'Take'},
{'recipient_id': '5517b1', 'status': 'Take'}]}
]
```

I have around 5K records to be transformed and looking for efficient method to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

json_ls = [{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517a5'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517a6'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517a7'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517a9'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517aa'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517ab'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517ac'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001b', 'recipient_id': '5517ad'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517ae'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001c', 'recipient_id': '5517af'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517b0'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001d', 'recipient_id': '5517b1'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b2'},
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b3'}, 
{'status': 'Take', 'batch_number': '1001a', 'recipient_id': '5517b4'}]

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in json_ls:
    result[i.pop("batch_number")].append(i)
result = [{'batch_number': k, 'recipients':v}  for k, v in result.items()]    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'batch_number': '1001a',
  'recipients': [{'recipient_id': '5517a5', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517aa', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517ab', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517b2', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517b3', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517b4', 'status': 'Take'}]},
 {'batch_number': '1001b',
  'recipients': [{'recipient_id': '5517a6', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517ac', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517ad', 'status': 'Take'}]},
 {'batch_number': '1001c',
  'recipients': [{'recipient_id': '5517a7', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517ae', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517af', 'status': 'Take'}]},
 {'batch_number': '1001d',
  'recipients': [{'recipient_id': '5517a9', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517b0', 'status': 'Take'},
                 {'recipient_id': '5517b1', 'status': 'Take'}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh, perfect solution for my problem.